# oauth2 refresh token with long expiration

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I have a oauth2 api where my token expires in 1 day but I wish the user be able to keep logged and in this case the client request a refresh token to expires in 1 year from now. The problem is when I got the refresh token to expires in 1 day instead of 1 year.

Here are some code snippets to help you understood my scenario.

Startup.cs

```
// Enable authentication by token
        var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/auth/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AuthorizationCodeExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
            Provider = container.Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>(GetAuthorizationProviderName()),
            RefreshTokenProvider = container.Resolve<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>()
        };
```

RefreshTokenProvider.cs [IAuthenticationTokenProvider]

```
        public async Task CreateAsync(AuthenticationTokenCreateContext context)
    {
        var clientId = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];

        if (clientId.IsEmpty()) return;

        var refreshToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

            var application = _repository.GetAllApplicationsAsync().ByAppId(clientId);

            var token = new RefreshToken(
                plainTextToken: refreshToken,
                issuedUtc: DateTime.UtcNow,
                expiresUtc: DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1),
                serializedAuthTicket: context.SerializeTicket());

            await _repository.SaveAsync(token);

            context.Ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = token.IssuedUtc;
            context.Ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = token.ExpiresUtc;

            context.SetToken(refreshToken);
        }
    }

public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");
        context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigin);

        var hashedTokenId = Crypto(context.Token);

            var token = await _repository.GetAllTokensAsync().ByTokenAsync(hashedTokenId);

            if (token != null)
            {
                context.DeserializeTicket(token.SerializedAuthTicket);

                await _repository.DeleteAsync(hashedTokenId);
            }
    }
```

OAuth2Provider.cs [IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider]

```
public override async Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
    {
        var originalClient = context.Ticket.Properties.Dictionary["as:client_id"];
        var currentClient = context.ClientId;

        if (originalClient != currentClient)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_clientId", "Refresh token is issued to a different clientId.");
            return;
        }

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Identity);
        claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("newClaim", "refreshToken"));

        var updatedTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(claimsIdentity, context.Ticket.Properties);
        context.Validated(updatedTicket);
    }
```

This is the response from token api

```
{
"access_token": "qeZlgDHBkqx0m4TVPzhjr6ioOdATTW0KrweHKhawVLhXeBGGdFgB1B0GL9_[omitted]",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 86399,
"refresh_token": "8925f5070f0249508761009378fde92a",
"username": "master",
"last_logon": "Tue, 17 Jul 2018 15:59:12 GMT",
"as:client_id": "abc123",
".issued": "Tue, 17 Jul 2018 19:19:44 GMT",
".expires": "Wed, 18 Jul 2018 19:19:44 GMT"
```

}

This is the response from refresh token api.

```
{
"access_token": "-AnSGFnLGKO1QnzkmP0QyHno5uR-[omitted]",
"token_type": "bearer",
"expires_in": 86399,
"refresh_token": "32b5050dc8ec488abaf1df6bb3c96ec0",
"username": "master",
"last_logon": "Tue, 17 Jul 2018 15:59:12 GMT",
"as:client_id": "abc123",
".issued": "Tue, 17 Jul 2018 19:23:24 GMT",
".expires": "Wed, 18 Jul 2018 19:23:24 GMT"
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After going through the question, I do believe that when you request for the refresh token, it will be of the same exact duration as the one you got before. For the test purpose you can change the first call to be to get the token for 1 year and see if it refreshes for another year.

If you want to change the time span of the token expiration I believe you have to request another token with new time span and then refresh the token.